# CSS - How do I blur the left and right side of an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a blur effect on the left and right side of a full page image but I have no idea how to go about it. An example of what I would like to achieve is here. http://www.uchicago.edu/ .

I want them to look like this.

[image: example image 1]

[image: example image 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this. Experiment  with the opacity value and color on left and right.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's okay, I fixed it by giving it a Z-index of 1

Answer (score 1):

This is how they did it. Make parent component of your image to have this css:

```
   background-image: url(//d3qi0qp55mx5f5.cloudfront.net/www/i/features/20170710_Poetry_Family.jpg?mtime=1498506744);
  position: absolute;
   width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
 filter: blur(5px);
```

Comment: Now imagine I have a dynamic slideshow of different images. Will I have to change the background-image attribute for each of the images?

Comment: Nice with the blur but not very semantic with background image.

Answer (score 1):

You could even do that using pseudo selector `:before` and `:after`,

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.7);
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve the desired effect with a combination of a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), inset [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) and color matching.

The pseudo-element is an overlay, you add a `box-shadow` property and set it to `inset` to render the shadow inward. You also set the amount of desired blur (too much blur on too many elements cripples performance)

The rest is just sizing the element to only render the effect on the sides.

```css
.blur {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.blur:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 135%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 15px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
</div>
```

You can also produce more refined effects using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property like so:

```css
.blur {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.blur:after {
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/300/300");
  background-size: cover;
  content: "";
  transform: scale(1.15,1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:.9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(10px) saturate(1.5);
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
</div>
```

but this is performance-heavy and [not supported on all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

Answer (score 1):

If your html is generated by a script, you may use the same image twice on top of each others, one can be blured and rescaled :

example within a basic CSS slide show

```css
figure {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure img,
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

figure img:first-child {
  filter: blur(2px) saturate(50%);
  width: 500px;
  position: static;
}

figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  height: 67px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 497px;
  height: 316px;
  border: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  left: 0;
}

figure+figure {
  left: 500px;
}

figure:focus {
  left: -500px;
  z-index: 2;
}

figure:focus+figure {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
Click image to slide to next one
<div>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/1" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/1" />
    <figcaption>
      people 1, click or tab to show next
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/2" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/2" />
    <figcaption>
      people 2, click to next
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/3" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/3" />
    <figcaption>
      people 3, click to next
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/4" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/4" />
    <figcaption>
      people 4
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/5" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/5" />
    <figcaption>
      people 5, click to next
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/6" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/6" />
    <figcaption>
      people 6, click to next
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/7" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/7" />
    <figcaption>
      people 7, click to next
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/8" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/8" />
    <figcaption>
      people 8, click to next
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure tabindex="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/9" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/people/9" />
    <figcaption>
      people 9, click me to start again
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linear gradient:

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.7) 10%, transparent 10%, transparent 90%, rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.7) 90%), url("http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/animals/") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Or two inset box shadows:

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/animals/") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 10vw 0 0 rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.7), inset -10vw 0 0 rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.7);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```